# Angular router: Child route can be called without parent url

Tags: angular, router

I have one router like this:

```html
const firstRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'parent-url',
        children: secondRoutes
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And second one like this:

```html
export const secondRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'child-route',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'child-route',
        component: ChildComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

My ChildComponent can be called with /child-route or /parent-url/child-route. I want to disable calling my function with both routs, so to set able to call it only with /parent-url/child-route.

I dont know how to check if there is /parent-url and if it is not there to disable calling ChildComponent without that /parent-url . in whole url?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you ever find the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a new project with angular-cli and generate a childComponent.

My routing works great, here is my `app-routig.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

const secondRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'child-route',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'child-route',
        component: ChildComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'parent-url',
        children: secondRoutes
      }
    ]
  }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```